# QSettings(Qt 5.4): setValue doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

In my .cpp I'm using QSettings.
This worked before, in Qt 4.8:

```
#include <QSettings>


----------


QSettings settings;
settings.setValue("time_axis_direction", 1);
int test_var = settings.value("time_axis_direction").toInt();


----------
```

In `test_var` the program returns 0, what's the cause?
I used Qt with VS Add-In.

Comment: Try to call `QSettings::sync()` between writing and reading the value.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#QSettings-5), you have to set organization name and application name:

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("My Organization");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("My Application");
QSettings settings;
```

Or right in the constructor:

```
QSettings settings("My Organization", "My Application");
```

This will create `HKCU\SOFTWARE\My Organization\My Application` registry entry to store your settings (on Windows).

> If QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName() and QCoreApplication::setApplicationName() has not been previously called, the QSettings object will not be able to read or write any settings, and status() will return AccessError.